# How to 'finish' a code, so that it doesn't just keep running

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, line-breaks

I'm trying to make the class dice roll game with Python. Below is my code. I can't figure out how finish the game, i.e. when "N" is selected, I get never-ending repetition of the final print (that is, "I hope you enjoyed playing dice. Have a great day!")

```js
import random
import time
player = random.randint(1,6)
ai = random.randint(1,6)
cont = str(input('Roll the dice? Y/N'))
while cont == "Y":
    print ("You are rolling...")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("You rolled " + str(player))
    print("The computer rolls...." )
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("The computer rolled " + str(ai))
    if player > ai:
        print("You win")
    if ai > player:
        print("You lose")
    cont2 = str(input('Would you like to play again? Y/N'))
while cont != "Y" or cont2 != "Y":
    break
print ("I hope you enjoyed playing dice. Have a great day!")
```

Comment: change `cont2 =` to `cont =` and remove the second `while`

Comment: The dices are not very interesting. Always the same numbers.

Comment: True :). A beginner exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Where you asign the next user input to `cont2`, you can just reassign to `cont`. This will 'break' the while loop if the user presses 'N'. You then won't need the second while loop anymore.

Edit: As stated above by Daniel, your code nog always gives the same computer dice roll. Yoy should change the `ai` line to inside the while-loop.

```
import random
import time
player = random.randint(1,6)
# remove ai = random.randint(1,6) here
cont = str(input('Roll the dice? Y/N'))
while cont == "Y":
    print ("You are rolling...")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("You rolled " + str(player))
    print("The computer rolls...." )
    ai = random.randint(1,6) # <-- add here again
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("The computer rolled " + str(ai))
    if player > ai:
        print("You win")
    if ai > player:
        print("You lose")
    cont = str(input('Would you like to play again? Y/N')) # <-- this line is changed

print ("I hope you enjoyed playing dice. Have a great day!")
```

You can also make it more robust for given user input by adding `.upper()` after the input. So: `cont = str(input('Roll the dice? Y/N')).upper()`. If a user then inputs 'y' instead of 'Y', it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import random                                                                  
 import time                                                                    
 cont = str(input('Roll the dice? Y/N'))                                        
 while cont == "Y":                                                             
    player = random.randint(1,6)                                               
    ai = random.randint(1,6)                                                   
    print ("You are rolling...")                                               
    time.sleep(3)                                                              
    print ("You rolled " + str(player))                                        
    print("The computer rolls...." )                                           
    time.sleep(3)                                                              
    print ("The computer rolled " + str(ai))                                   
    if player > ai:                                                            
        print("You win")                                                       
    if ai > player:                                                            
        print("You lose")                                                      
    cont2 = str(input('Would you like to play again? Y/N'))                                                                                                    
    if cont2.lower() == 'y':                                                   
        cont == "Y"                                                            
    elif cont2.lower() == 'n':                                                 
        cont == "N"                                                            
        break                                                                  
 print ("I hope you enjoyed playing dice. Have a great day!"
```

Just to make your code more robust, I have included the rolled dice values inside the `while` loop. Second you can get rid of the second `while` loop with an `if--else` to make your code more readable and understandable.